# ETW Logging - TraceEventSession enable multiple event provider for listener

Tags: c#, logging, etw, etw-eventsource

I am developing a ETW listener to listen to all available event sources in my system.

Q1:
Please find the sample code below:

```
providerName = "ETW-TEST-APPLICATION";
sessionName = "ETW-TEST-APPLICATION";

using (var session = new TraceEventSession(sessionName, null))
{
    try
    {
        session.StopOnDispose = true;
        session.BufferSizeMB = 100;
        Console.CancelKeyPress +=
            delegate(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e) { session.Dispose(); };

        using (source = new ETWTraceEventSource(sessionName, TraceEventSourceType.Session))
        {

            var parser = new DynamicTraceEventParser(source);
            parser.AddDynamicProvider(new ProviderManifest(Environment.CurrentDirectory +
                                                           "\\ETWApplicationRegister." +
                                                           providerName +
                                                           ".etwManifest.man"));

            parser.All += delegate(TraceEvent data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("ProviderName : " + data.ProviderName);
                Console.WriteLine("ProviderGuid : " + data.ProviderGuid);
                Console.WriteLine("EventID : " + data.ID);
                Console.WriteLine("Level : " + data.Level);
                Console.WriteLine("Channel : " + data.Channel);
                Console.WriteLine("Task : " + data.Task);
                Console.WriteLine("TaskName : " + data.TaskName);
                Console.WriteLine("TimeStamp : " + data.TimeStamp);
                Console.WriteLine("FormattedMessage : " + data.FormattedMessage);
                Console.WriteLine("PayLoad : " + data.PayloadByName("jsonArgs"));
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------");
            };

            session.EnableProvider(providerGuid);

            source.Process(); //On execution of this statement system listens to the events
        }
    }
}
```

This code holds good for one event source namely "ETW-TEST-APPLICATION". I would like this listener to be used for multiple event sources "ETW-TEST-APPLICATION2","ETW-TEST-APPLICATION3" etc.

Please let me know about the options available for achieving this. I tried with threading but didnt work.

Q2:
Also let me know if i can have multiple session.EnableProvider's, i want to enable only informational & Error messages, but ignore Warning messages session.EnableProvider(providerGuid,TraceEventLevel.Informational);
session.EnableProvider(providerGuid,TraceEventLevel.Error);

Comment: I am able to work with Async calls to achieve this.

Comment: Sorry i am not able to close this question. will do it after Bounty ends.

Answer (score 2):

Q1: You shouldn't need more than one ETWTraceEventSource to enable multiple providers if they are in one session.  That said, if you are forced to you may have to create a new DynamicTraceEventParser per source, then hook your event handler to each parser.

Q2: Here's a simplified example of how I've enable multiple providers by searching an assembly:

```
    void EnableAllEventSources()
    {
        foreach (var es in GetEventSourceNamesFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);)
            _session.EnableProvider(es);
    }

    IEnumerable<string> GetEventSourceNamesFromAssembly(Assembly assembly)
    {
        return assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.BaseType == (typeof(EventSource)))
            .Select(t => {
                var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(t, typeof(EventSourceAttribute));
                return ((EventSourceAttribute)attribute).Name;
            });
    }
```